# Ski Resort taken over by terrorists

Tags: identify-this-movie

I'm looking for a movie about a ski resort that was taken over by terrorists.

A few scenes that I remember:

The lead terrorist is holding a gun to a women's head while a police sniper tries taking aim on a helicopter. After a few minutes of standoff, the helicopter is shot down by another terrorist using an RPG type of weapon (though it looks pretty different). Then a news agency chopper comes by and films the lead terrorist yelling his demands until he waves them away.

Later on in the film, the good guys take the resort back over. During the takeover, a couple is being chased by a terrorist on a snow-tractor of some sort. As he is about to run them over, another good guy shoots him from a long distance with a sniper rifle.

The last scene I remember is the lead terrorist on top of another tractor yelling at a good guy about to kill him (I think) and suddenly the tractor blows up from another good guy who had gotten ahold of one of the RPGs.

It was color, American, and I saw it probably 10 years ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [**Icebreaker**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0179861/) (2000) with a pre-*Lord of the Rings* Sean Astin.

> At the the Killington ski resort something has gone awry. Evil terrorists led by the sinister Greig have taken the resort hostage with a stolen nuclear device. It's up to Ski Patrol bum Matt Foster to save the day... and his fiancé.

The helicopter being shot down as a roughly the 1hr mark and, of course, the terrorist blown away with a surface to air missile at the end.

Whole movie here.